# Turing machine to compare binary

Tags: turing-machines

I am trying to write, using a Turing simulation, so in the form:
    `0 1 * r 0
    0 0 * r 0
    0 # * * 3
    0 x * r 0
    0 y * r 0`

...a program that takes two binary values separated by a ">" e.g. 1010>111 which will halt-yes if left>right and halt-no is left>right.

I would like to compare solutions, if you're interested, leave your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode for an approach I might use:

1. Strip out all leading zeroes from the LHS and RHS by replacing them with some symbol - (not blank but not 0, 1, or >).
2. Check to make sure the number of remaining digits in the LHS and RHS are the same. If not, we can immediately say whether LHS > RHS or not based on the relative lengths. Do this by bouncing back and forth and changing 0, 1 to 0', 1' until/unless you run out on one side without having marked one you needed to.
3. If we're still checking, the process now is simple: compare the first digit of LHS and RHS; if LHS(1) > RHS(1), then LHS > RHS; if LHS(1) < RHS(1), LHS < RHS. If LHS(1) = RHS(1), remove both of these, and do step 3 over again. If all the digits are gone, the numbers were equal and you halt-no.

Step #1 is O(n) in the input length, since we can do this in a single sweep from left to right. We can then roll back to the beginning of tape.

Step #2 is O(n^2) since the TM is basically doing n steps, n - 1 steps, ..., 2 steps = n(n+1)/2 - 1 steps in total to count the LHS and RHS.

Step #3 is O(n^2) since the TM is basically doing n/2 steps n/2 times, for a total of about n^2/4 steps in total.

Time complexity is thus O(n^2), space complexity is O(n) (we use the input as scratch memory).